# What is the pattern matching for this?

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone help me to come up with a regex for something like : 
AC::CC::DD::EE::FF::EE
(two letters or numbers , but not a fancy character like % or any other, followed by ::). 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This regular expression will do.

```
/^([\dA-F]{2}::){5}[\dA-F]{2}$/
```

**Example.**

```
/^([\dA-F]{2}::){5}[\dA-F]{2}$/.test("AC::CC::DD::EE::FF::EE") // true
/^([\dA-F]{2}::){5}[\dA-F]{2}$/.test("AC::CC::DD::E3E::FF::EE") // false
```

Comment: you want the entire form ?
i already got the answer from you and the others.
thanx to all of you

Comment: i ticked the true signed. i didn't make any down vote.
i am trying to make an up vote but it says I need 15 reputations.

Comment: @Alsaket Thanks. But the question was not for you. It was anyone who have down-voted

Answer (score 2):

I've not tested this, but almost all regexp interpreters should recognize this pattern as doing what you want: `[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9](::[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9])*`

If you want it to ONLY match this pattern on the line then it should be like so:

`^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9](::[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9])*$`

Note that this pattern will match `A1` or match `AC:CC:DD:E1:FF:EE:ZZ:MK:LM:Z0`. (Did you want it to only have six fields instead of 1 or more?)

I recommend [this website](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/) for a cheat sheet for regexps.

Answer (score 2):

(two letters or numbers , but not a fancy character like % or any other, followed by ::)

```
[\w\d]{2}::
```

But did you need to match the entire string or just that in that statement?

Comment: generally two numbers or alphabets or combination also can. 
the whole sentence will be six (nums or alphabets separated by :: ).
thanx Jayson for ur feedback

Comment: No prob, and thanks. Hope this thread gave you all you needed.

Answer (score 2):

`'AC::CC::DD::EE::FF::EE::55::AA'.match(/\w{2,}(::|$)|\d{2,}(::|$)/g);`

Output

`["AC::", "CC::", "DD::", "EE::", "FF::", "EE::", "55::", "AA"]`